# Forward logs from specific path on a kubernetes pod to stdout

Tags: logging, kubernetes

I have some logs in Kubernetes Pod on specific path `/mnt/logs`, and I would like to forward them to stdout so I can see them when I execute `kubectl logs ....`. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

May try overriding the container command:

```
command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: ["-c", "touch /mnt/logs/my.log && tail -f /mnt/logs/my.log & run_your_app"]
```

Note the second conjunction is `&` - this is to ensure `tail` is in the background.